The subtotal sum on the cart page is incorrect (Bookable product)
I'm building a reservation website for "day use" ticket sales using the Woocommerce Bookings plugin. However, I need to add custom fields based on the quantity of tickets (persons) the customer selects. I'm using these two codes to generate this interaction between the cart and the checkout:
For the cart page (updates the quantity of items in the cart):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'update_cart_item_quantity_for_bookings', 20, 3 );

function update_cart_item_quantity_for_bookings( $quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    // Only for bookable product items
    if( isset($cart_item['booking']) && isset($cart_item['booking']['_qty']) ) {
        // Returns the exact quantity from variations
        return $cart_item['booking']['_qty'];
    }

    return $quantity;
}


For the Checkout (Creates custom fields):
// WooCommerce checkout custom fields based on quantity
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'participant_details' );

function participant_details($checkout) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $i = 1;
    for($k=2; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        $i++;
        print ('<h3>Please enter details for participant '.$i.'</h3>');
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Full Name'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter full name'),
            'required'      => true, // Making the field mandatory
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ));
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_cpf'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('CPF'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter CPF number'),
            'required'      => true, // Making the field mandatory
            ),
            $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_cpf'.$i ));
    }
}

/**
 * Save field values
 */

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_order_field_meta');

function save_custom_order_field_meta($order_id)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    $i = 1;
    for($k=2; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        $i++;
        if (!empty($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'Participant Name'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_full_name'.$i]));
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['cstm_cpf'.$i])) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'Participant CPF'.$i, sanitize_text_field($_POST['cstm_cpf'.$i]));
        }
    }
}


The interaction is working, the custom fields are being generated according to the quantity of people. However, the subtotal in the cart is incorrect; the value is completely wrong. For example: If I select 3 tickets on the product page (each costing $10) and click the "Buy Tickets" button, it correctly adds the 3 tickets to my sidebar cart with the total value of $30. But when I proceed to the cart page or the checkout page, the value becomes $90 (it multiplies as 3x3x$10 = $90).
I've tried using ChatGPT to create variations of the code, but I couldn't get anything. I want the subtotal to be calculated normally, as per the default WooCommerce behavior.
Note: I'm using a 'Code Snippets' plugin to apply these codes.
